# Liferay Structure Predefined Value

Tags: liferay

Which table in Liferay stores the predefined values given for a structure.

Also is there a facility in Liferay to populate these values dynamically using webservices?

Comment: Is it about Web Content structure's field's default value?

Comment: Yes. The values that go into <dynamic-content>

Comment: You should put more information in your question because is very general. What version of Liferay are you using? Enterprise or Community?

Answer (score 1):

The API used to be [JournalStructureService](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalStructureService.html), however, as the documentation states, this has been replaced with the Dynamic Data Display API, which, for example, you can find under [DDMStructureService](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/dynamicdatamapping/service/DDMStructureService.html) in version 6.2.

This gives you a hint where to find the underlying data, however, you *don't* want to manually write to the database. You *do want* to use the API to change values. Trust me. Consider the database to be an implementation detail and leave it alone - if nothing else to make your next upgrade experience easier. You should *never* change any values in the database manually without knowing *exactly* what you're doing. And, trust me, the keyword here is "exactly", and you'll fail to know *all* the possible side effects. Don't touch it.

Comment: Thanks for the info Olaf.
But if its not a good idea to change the API, is there any clean approach to populate structure dynamic-content dynamically. I guess current Liferay implementation does permit storing default values but these values are static, I am looking for something like populating these values using variables.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is about: The API (DDMStructureService and related) is available to be called and set the values as you like. You might have to use a different UI to make it happen as well, but Liferay does nothing else than to write to the API, you can do the same. And when you're there, you can interpret variables to suit your needs. If I understand your scenario correctly, you'll have to work a bit on the UI as well. Alternatively you can write a hook, overriding some of the services and do variable replacement when an article is saved

Answer (score 0):

As said @Olaf, depends on Liferay version you will need to use the JournalStructureService or the DDMStructureService. So, if you want to use the Liferay Service by web api you have two options the Axis api where you can obtain WSDL (domain:port/api/axis) or you can use the Json api (domain:port/api/axis). In many cases you are going to need a token to use this services.